# Erased HDD "Free Space" with 0x00, but now Windows 7 is reporting a false storage size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, vmdk

I have a virtual disk (VMDK) on an SSD, and I ran a program (DiskGenius -> Erase Free Space) to erase free space on that VMDK. It erased about 800 GB of room which used to be available to me in Windows 7.

However, now when I boot Windows 7 in VMWare Workstation, it says there's only 644 MB free. Where did all my free space go and how I can I recover it?

Should I run a defrag (not really wanting to do that since it's destroy my SSD write cycles) or perhaps a `chkdsk` on boot up Windows 7?

DiskGenius:

[image: Image: DiskGenius]

Windows 7 Explorer Report:

[image: Image: Windows 7 Explorer Report]

[VMWare HDD Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oY87.png)

[VMWare Cleanup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpffq.png)

Comment: virtual disk (VMDK)  -- VMware ?  looks like it. Shut Down Windows 7 VM.   VMware Menu, VM, Manage, Clean up machine. That recovers space in the guest machine.

Comment: There's no such option (screenshot attached to my initial post under "VMWare HDD Options").

EDIT: Ah! It's under the actual menu bar (image attached as "VMWare Cleanup"). Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The option is in the VMware main ribbon (VMware Workstation).  I am not sure about Player.

Comment: If you resolve your issue, please don't hesitate to answer your own question and accept the answer. A nice description of your solution will help others down the road :-)

Comment: I just booted the VM up, and Windows 7 is still reporting 644 MB free so it didn't seem to work. Any ideas? I'm currently running a chkdsk.

Comment: You performed the cleanup while the machine was turned off?  I would also perform the Compact and Defragment. Be sure you are not mounting the virtual HDD while you perform these operations.

Comment: Yes, I performed the clean up whilst it was powered off. I will try defragmenting and then running the compact options in VMWare (as seen in my image "VMWare HDD Options").

Comment: Okay, running a chkdsk fixed it. Thanks for your help everyone :)

Comment: Please put up an answer and accept it, rather then including it in the post. For future readers.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: Run in VMWare the 'Cleanup Disks' option from the toolbar, and then run a chkdsk in Windows (performed on bootup).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).